# Client/Server Interaction - How to create ability to delete items?

Tags: client-server, crud

I have a website with "things" that you can create, edit, and delete inside the dashboard (specific to each user).  When viewing a certain item in the dashboard, you can choose to delete it or edit it.  I want to have a button that allows for delete, followed by a confirmation box ("are you sure you want to delete").

What is the most best way to set this up?  Do I create a form with hidden values and the confirmation window will submit the form?  Do I create a button with a link for a GET request that deletes it on the server side? (`http://domain.com/delete?id=5`).  This is more a question about how the client and server should interact in this manner?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make delete as link and then call php script that delete this thing